# pax package not working with files which having space in its name

Tags: pdftex, pdf, links, pax

I am using PdfLaTeX with pax package (pdfbox). I need to combine the uploaded pdf files and generate a composite pdf with links clickable.

It is working when I upload pdf files with no spaces in its name (eg., test1.pdf, test2.pdf). But links are not working when I upload files with space in its name (eg., test 1.pdf, test 2.pdf).

Why? How to solve this issue?

Comment: well the easiest is not to use spaces. Lots of tools get confused by spaces as they are also use to separate commands. Perhaps you can also quote a file name somewhere, but without a test setup to reproduce your problem it is difficult to say.

Comment: spaces are not allowed in URL apart from being tricky generally to handle in file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue.

If you are using pax package and uploading files with space in its name (ie test 1.pdf , test 2.jpg etc).

Before you use the file in includepdf function, you need to add double quotes before and after the filename (ie "test 1".pdf , "test 2".jpg etc)
Thus you can create test 1.pax successfully.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply replace the spaces with, say, underscores? That way it should work anywhere without problems.

Comment: i think no, it may change the file name. the file which we upload and the create pax file names will be different